# Suggestion to write a number as a sum of three numbers where each number is at least two

Tags: algorithm, sum, combinations

I'm trying to find all possible combinations to write a number as a sum of three numbers, where each number is at least 2.

So basically for 6 it would be like:

2 2 2

For 7 it would be:

2 2 3 or 2 3 2 or 3 2 2

I was wondering if there's a better approach to this than running 3 loops.

EDIT:

```
public class Problem {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        int N = 7, n1, n2, n3;

        for (n1 = 2; n1 <= N; n1++) {
            for (n2 = 2; n2 <= N; n2++) {
                for (n3 = 2; n3 <= N; n3++) {
                    if ( (n1+n2+n3)==N ) {
                        System.out.println(n1 + " " + n2 + " " + n3);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This solution works, but I was thinking if there's another approach to this.

Comment: Consider the combinations of three numbers that sum to N-3.

Comment: Your solution is outputting combinations, while halfway in your question you seem to look for an output of the *number* of combinations (`result`). The latter can be done more efficiently than the first, so you should clear up what you want.

Comment: One note: when you have the first two numbers the third is given from those (`n3 = N - n1 - n2`) - you just need to check that it's within range (>= 2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking to [partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)) an integer `n` into `k` parts, where each part has a minimum value `min`. The classic approach here would be to use recursion.

Initially we create an array to hold the parts, initialize them to `min` and remove `k*min` from `n` to get the remainder.

```
static List<int[]> partitions(int n, int k, int min)
{
    int[] parts = new int [k];
    Arrays.fill(parts, min);
    
    int rem = n - k*min;
    
    List<int[]> results = new ArrayList<>();
    partition(results, parts, rem);
    return results;
}
```

We now use a recursive method to explore adding 1 to each of the parts in turn. If the remainder reaches 0 we have a solution and add the current solution to the results.

```
static void partition(List<int[]> results, int[] parts, int rem)
{
    if(rem <= 0)
    {
        if(rem == 0) results.add(parts.clone());
        return;
    }
    
    for(int i=0; i<parts.length; i++)
    {
        parts[i] += 1;
        partition(results, parts, rem-1);
        parts[i] -= 1;
    }
}
```

Test:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    for(int[] res : partitions(7, 3, 2))
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(res));       
}
```

Output:

```
[3, 2, 2]
[2, 3, 2]
[2, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

it is my suggestion

create a class to model each answer of equation here we create a static inner class to model each answer:

```java
public static class Answer{
    private int a;
    private int b;
    private int c;
    public Answer(int a, int b, int c) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
    }

    public int getA() {
        return a;
    }


    public int getB() {
        return b;
    }

    public int getC() {
        return c;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Answer answer = (Answer) o;
        return a == answer.a &&
                b == answer.b &&
                c == answer.c;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(a, b, c);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Answer{" +
                "a=" + a +
                ", b=" + b +
                ", c=" + c +
                '}';
    }
}
```

then a recursive algorithm to produce results:

```java
// don't call this method directly only combination method must call it
private Set<Answer> combinationHelper(int n){
    Set<Answer> results = new HashSet<>();
    if(n < 0)
        return results;
    if(n  == 0) {
        results.add(new Answer(0, 0, 0));
        return results;
    }

    Set<Answer> remain = combinationHelper(n - 1);
    remain.forEach(element -> {
        int a = element.getA();
        int b = element.getB();
        int c = element.getC();
        results.add(new Answer(a + 1, b, c));
        results.add(new Answer(a, b + 1, c));
        results.add(new Answer(a, b, c + 1));
    });
    return results;
}

public Set<Answer> combination(int n){
    Set<Answer> results = combinationHelper(n - 6);
    return results.stream()
                  .map(a -> new Answer(a.getA() + 2, a.getB() + 2, a.getC() + 2))
                  .collect(Collectors.toSet());
}
```

then call it like this:

```java
System.out.println(new Comb().combination(6));
System.out.println(new Comb().combination(7));
```

which produces results:

```java
[Answer{a=2, b=2, c=2}]
[Answer{a=2, b=3, c=2}, Answer{a=3, b=2, c=2}, Answer{a=2, b=2, c=3}]
```

**if you don't like the idea of adding another model class to your application you can easily use arrays instead**

---

non-recursive approach:

```java
public List<String> combination(int n){
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    if(n < 6)
        return result;
    BitSet bits = new BitSet(n - 6);
    bits.set(0, n - 6);
    IntStream
            .range(0, n - 5)
            .forEach(i ->
                    IntStream.range(i, n - 5).forEach(j ->
                            result.add(String.format("%s %d %d %d %s", "{", bits.get(0, i).length() + 2, bits.get(i, j).length() + 2, bits.get(j, n).length() + 2, "}"))));
    return result;

}
```

results for non-recursive approach:

for input 7:

```java
[{ 2 2 3 }, { 2 3 2 }, { 3 2 2 }]
```

for input 6:

```java
[{ 2 2 2 }]
```